# TextMate ConTeXt bundle

Tags: context, paths, textmate

I am in macOS High Sierra, with TextMate 2 and the (outdated, from 2010) [ConTeXt bundle](https://github.com/pgundlach/context.tmbundle). And I have MacTeX 2018 installed.

I tried to compile something and it said that my PATH was something and that I didn't have “context” in it. So I changed the PATH variable of TextMate to:

```
$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/context/stubs/unix
```

because in that last part I think is where context is, but now when I try to compile a ConTeXt document I get

```
env: texlua: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Crosspost on the mailing list, where Mojca already answered: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/093289.html

Comment: @TeXnician Do you want to add an answer instead of me answering my own question?

Comment: No, because basically Mojca answered it. Therefore, you should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in the ConTeXt mailing list, and quickly Mojca answered https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2018/093289.html. She has an account here, but seems he doesn't

Basically, the PATH is wrong.

- MacTeX path should be before `/opt/local/bin` (used by macports, and may be homebrew —which is the one I use);
- `/usr/texbin` is from older operating systems and is no longer useful by default in High Sierra for example; and
- the binaries are in `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

So the PATH ends up being

```
$PATH:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

and now it compiles.